# fastlane gradle build version name and code different than one uploaded to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, fastlane, firebase-app-distribution

When building and uploading a test build to firebase the version code and name that the APK is build with are different than the version code and name that is visible in Firebase app distribution. How can this be?

This is my fastlane command:

```
UI.message "Android #{versionName} (#{versionNumber}) - #{releaseNote}"
    gradle(
        task: 'assemble',
        build_type: 'Release',
        flags: "--warning-mode none -x lint",
        properties: {
            "android.injected.version.code" => versionNumber,
            "android.injected.version.name" => versionName,
            "android.injected.signing.store.file" => ENV['STORE_FILE'],
            "android.injected.signing.store.password" => ENV['STORE_PASSWORD'],
            "android.injected.signing.key.alias" => ENV['KEY_ALIAS'],
            "android.injected.signing.key.password" => ENV['KEY_PASSWORD']
        },
        print_command_output: true
    )
```

Which outputs:

```
 $ /gradlew assembleRelease -p . -Pandroid.injected.version.code=202337 
    -Pandroid.injected.version.name=7.4.2 
    -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file= 
    -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password= 
    -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias=
    -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password= 
    --warning-mode none -x lint
```

As we can see it is building a APK with version 7.4.2 202337

Then when i upload the artifact to firebase i get this message:

**Uploaded APK successfully and created release 7.4.1 (202335).**

These versions do not match and i really do not understand how this happens...

To upload the APK i use this:

```
firebase_app_distribution(
        app: "",
        groups: "",
        release_notes: ""
    )
```

Can anyone please help me?